# Compute $\int_{x=-\infty} ^\infty \frac{\tanh (x)}{\prod_{k=1}^N (x-(x_k+i))}dx$

Tags: calculus, complex-integration, hyperbolic-functions

I am trying to compute the following complex integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\frac{\tanh\left(x\right)}
{\prod_{k = 1}^{N}\,
\left[\,{x - \left(\,{x_{k} + \mathrm{i}}\,\right)}\right]}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
where $\forall k, x_{k}\in \mathbb{R}$, $\mathrm{i}$ imaginary unit and $N \geq 2$.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: If possible, could you provide some context as to where you found this question and what have you tried?

Comment: Hello, this equation comes from physics. It's more or less a dressed propagator of a statistical field theory. What I've tried so far is an analysis of the poles. The pole of tanh are on the imaginary axis and there are infinitely many of them. Because of the denonimator the infinite sum that pops out when you compute the residues is now convergent and one is left with evaluating the sum instead. This seems promising, I'll keep you up to date.

Comment: To be more precise I think the equivalent problem is to calculate $2\pi i\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\prod_{k=1}^{N}(i(\pi(n+1/2)+1)+x_{k})}$